# Django class-based UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views

We are using Django 1.9.5. I am writing update company profile view. I want to have two fields on my update profile page:

- company `name`,
- `apikey`(generated with a dedicated function).

I want to change field `name` by hands and then save by clicking button Update. For filed `apikey` I want to have separated button which would automatically generate new key, save it to db and update my page.

I am overwriting `post` method at `UpdateView` class. But simething isn't working. Please take a look at my code:

`models.py:`

```
class Organization(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_('organisation display name'), max_length=512,
                            blank=True)


    apikey = models.CharField(_("API authentication key"), max_length=APIKEY_LENGTH,
                              default=get_apikey)
```

where `get_apikey` is

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string


APIKEY_PREFIX = "key-"
APIKEY_LENGTH = 80


def get_apikey():
    rnd_len = APIKEY_LENGTH - len(APIKEY_PREFIX)
    return "{}{}".format(
            APIKEY_PREFIX,
            get_random_string(rnd_len, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")
    )
```

`forms.py:`

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper, Layout
from orgs.models import Organization


class OrgProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrgProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ['name', 'apikey']
```

`views.py`

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, BaseUpdateView
from orgs.forms import OrgProfileForm
from orgs.models import Organization
from local.auth import get_apikey


class OrgProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = Organization
    template_name = 'orgs/orgprofile.html'
    form_class = OrgProfileForm
    url_name = 'profile'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        org_obj = Organization.objects.get(orgname=self.kwargs["orgname"])
        return org_obj

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import ipdb
        ipdb.set_trace()
        if '_key' in request.POST:
            org_obj = Organization.objects.get(orgname=self.kwargs["orgname"])
            org_obj.apikey = get_apikey()
            org_obj.save()
        self.object = org_obj
        return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`template.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Organization profile" %}{% endblock title %}
{% block header_title %}{% trans "Organization profile" %}{% endblock header_title %}


{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy form %}
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Generate new key' %}" name="_key">
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Update form' %}" name="_update">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Using `_key` and '_update' I want to differentiate between two buttons and actions update `name` and regenerate new `apikey`.

Answer (score 1):

Ohh, I have found the way around. In post request for updating `apikey` I need to:

- update `apikey` value in model and save it,
- redirect back to get request

`views.py`

```
class OrgProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = Organization
    template_name = 'orgs/orgprofile.html'
    form_class = OrgProfileForm
    url_name = 'profile'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        org_obj = Organization.objects.get(orgname=self.kwargs["orgname"])
        return org_obj

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if '_key' in request.POST:
            org_obj = Organization.objects.get(orgname=self.kwargs["orgname"])
            org_obj.apikey = get_apikey()
            org_obj.save()
            self.object = org_obj
            return super(BaseUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: In view functions, it's a good idea to return a 404 error when the user requests an instance that doesn't exist in the database. With your code, an incorrect `orgname` will result in a 500 server error. You can use the convenience function `django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404` instead. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404